# if cin true or false from variable C++

Tags: c++

please help me solve this..

```
int A=10;

cout<<"Answer this Question!";
cout<<"5 + 5 = ";cin>>A;
if(true) {
    cout<<"Correct!"<<endl;
} else if (false) {
    cout<<"Wrong!"<<endl;
}

getch();

}
```

the answer is A=10, if user input right answer from the `int A=10`then notif use cout "Correct!" and if wrong is "Wrong!" .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your above code,

> if (true)

always evaluates to true, so it will always print "Correct!".
However, I am guessing you are asking how do we check the user's input to see if they are correct? In that case, for your if statement, you want

```
if (A == 10)
```

and rather than an else if, just have an else statement since any answer other than 10 would be incorrect.

I suggest you look up basics of programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
  int A = 0;

  std::cout<<"Answer this question: 5 + 5 = "; 
  std::cin>>A;

  if(A == 10){
    std::cout<<"Correct"<<std::endl;
  }else{
    std::cout<<"Wrong"<<std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use two separate variables, one for the user's answer and one for the correct answer, and then compare them:

```
int correctAnswer = 10;
int userAnswer = 0;

cout << "Answer this Question!";
cout << "5 + 5 = ";
cin >> userAnswer;

if (correctAnswer == userAnswer) {
    cout << "Correct!" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "Wrong!" << endl;
}

getch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:)

```
//...

int B;

cin>>B;
if( A == B ) {
    cout<<"Correct!"<<endl;
} else {
    cout<<"Wrong!"<<endl;
}
```